# How to login google in react native without firebase in android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-signin

In react native I signed in google in ios. But I cant sign in google in android. I'm getting "A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred"
I use sha1. But i dont want to use firebase. Can you help me?